# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'angular'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build an Angular application and I am getting this error:

> error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'angular'

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you use the [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @pzaenger No I am not.

Comment: @Catalyst This error comes from just trying to build.

Comment: It comes from trying to build *something*, so... what?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was. I did not have `typings` installed.

I ran this:

```
npm i -g typings
```

to install `typings` globally.